# Stop interval once console.log display undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have created an interval function to keep running my function over and over again, after dom is refreshed with new data , at certain point, my console.log will display undefined. how do we capture or stop interval at the point where my console.log states undefined. Is there a function we could use to capture when console.log is triggered with undefined message?

Console.log

```
VM64:56         19
VM64:56         18
VM64:56         17
VM64:56         16
VM64:56         15
VM64:56         14
arc_all.js?v=5.1.3.0-1570239956:18     undefined display format making Product Design Risk NaN
arc_all.js?v=5.1.3.0-1570239956:18     undefined display format making <span data-dim="16" data-dimidx="2" class="crosstab-expand">  <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i></span> NaN
arc_all.js?v=5.1.3.0-1570239956:18     undefined display format making Anti-Competitive Conduct Risk NaN

VM64:56         13
...
VM64:56         0
```

To further elaborate my function, I have created this function, this function. function is working fine, I am unsure on what approach should I move towards in getting the message on console.log for undefined.

```
 function auto_refresh(start_count) {    
             window.repeat = setInterval(function(){ 
                    start_count = start_count - 1;
                        console.log(start_count)

                const request = $.ajax({ 
                 async : true,
                 success : function(){
                 setTimeout(customStyle(), 100)
                 },
              });

                if (start_count <= 0) {
                //Will clear interval when timer is 0
                  window.clearInterval(window.repeat);
                console.log('Inside the call function to be removed ' + window.repeat);
              }

             }, 1000);
          
            }
          
      //           // Call auto_refresh function and set 1 - 10 , e.g 10 will run interval for 10 seconds and => stop function ,
      //           // Bigger datasets , set to 30  - 150 or which is preferred 
                 auto_refresh(20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if the window.repeat value is undefined and then do something. For example, I've started the debugger when it's undefined:

```
if (window.repeat === undefined) {
  debugger;
} else {
  console.log('Inside the call function to be removed ' + window.repeat);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`setInterval` returns a value that can be passed to `clearInterval` to stop the interval.